# How to prevent Qt/cmake from adding carriage returns to resources on windows

Tags: qt, cmake, resources, qt5

I have a Qt program which was developed on Linux. In it are some user settings which are parsed from a config file. Of course, the users don't tend to have that config file during the first launch and we want things to work even if it isn't present, so a copy of the sensible defaults is stored in a resource text file, which is in the same format as the on-disk version would be.

I've run into an annoyance when running on windows...

The resources have had their `"\n"` line endings all converted to `"\r\n"` somewhere along the line! I'd really prefer to not have to alter the parsers to optionally accept more than one type of newline.

Is there a way to tell cmake to tell the Qt resource compiler to not do the conversion by passing a flag or similar?

**EDIT:** To clarify what's going on, I'll explain all of the little details of why I think qrc is adding the newlines...

First, I have a .qrc file which looks roughly like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>res/DefaultSettings.txt</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

It is added to the executable via cmake using code like this:

```
qt5_add_resources(QRC_SOURCES
    resource.qrc
)
```

and

```
add_executable(my_project
    resource.qrc
    main.cpp
)
```

finally, it is being loaded with code like this:

```
QByteArray loadResource(const QString &resource) {

    QResource res(resource);
    if(!res.isValid()) {
        qFatal("Failed to load internal resource");
    }

    // don't copy the data, if it's uncompressed, we can deal with it in place
    auto defaults = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(res.data()), res.size());

    if(res.isCompressed()) {
        defaults = qUncompress(defaults);
    }

    // NOTE: at this point, using a debugger, I observe 
    // "\r\n" newlines in the defaults byte array 
    return defaults;
}
```

Comment: First: That would it make hard for windows users to edit the file using notepad. Second: Why using a custom format and parser and not rely on already available and well-supported stuff (e.g. ini, xml, json, etc.)?

Comment: Well, it's an old code base that has been slowly modernized. JSON (and perhaps XML too) didn't really exist when the original was written. I'm not terribly concerned at this point about users being able to edit with notepad, though o suppose that could be a concern in the distant future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "resource" text file you mean a binary resource stored in the executable via qrc, then no: qrc will never alter the files - it doesn't discriminate between binary and text resources, it's all binary as far as it's concerned. Version control systems such as git may do that on checkin/checkout, though. You may also be reading the file using APIs that convert line endings. You'd ideally want to have a reproducer that outputs the file, and then another one that uses qrc to embed the file and then demonstrate the changed line endings.

Comment: As far as I can tell, qrc is in fact adding line endings, I'll edit the OP to demonstrate why I am confident of that shortly...

Comment: I stand corrected. I originally didn't catch why you were mentioning git, but it was in fact git which was adding the CRLF during checkout on windows!

Comment: Corollary: your parser should open the file in text mode to have the line endings converted back :) But also: git can have attributes added to any file to treat is as binary. That’ll help with reproducibility of the build. But also: your Windows users will not like you for having a configuration file that can’t be opened in Notepad as an editor of last resort (it doesn’t grok line endings other than native ones).

Comment: Truth be told, this project is a text editor which itself normalizes line endings... so if they choose notepad over it to edit the config files... something wen't wrong :-P

Comment: They can mess up the config file to make the editor unusable, so an ability to edit it without depending on the editor itself would be useful. Or at least a well-documented command line option to ignore the configuration file and use defaults instead.